# Salesforce report API - How to fetch more than 2000 records from Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

In salesforce, I have a report that has more than 2000 records (40000 rows). When I am trying to get that report via API I am getting only 2000 rows. It seems there is a limit of 2,000 results that can be returned for a given request. I am using the below code to get the data.

```
                    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(salesforceConnection.getInstanceUrl());
                    builder.setPath("/services/data/v39.0/analytics/reports/" + recordId);
    
                    final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(builder.build());
                    get.setHeader("Authorization", AppConstants.BEARER + salesforceConnection.getAccessToken());
                    final HttpResponse queryResponse = httpclient.execute(get);
```

Is there a way to query the remaining data?

Comment: Hi, 
Did you manage to solve it ?
I hit the same issue now .

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard limit in the Salesforce REST API that we have also encountered.

[image: Screenshot from Salesforce REST API documentation]

Source [on the REST API docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_limits_limitations.htm?q=2000)

I looked in vain for any update or method on the report API that would alter this.